# ParseError: Colon is expected (svelte with scss style) svelte unit testing

Tags: svelte

I am trying to write a test for the component which is using SCSS as default styling. But the test is throwing error that it's not able to understand SCSS

myComponent.svelte

```html
<div>Hello <span>world</span></div>
<style>
div {
 padding: 20px;
 span {
  font-weight: bold;
 }
}
</style>
```

Test File

```js
// mycomponent.test.js
import { render } from '@testing-library/svelte';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent.svelte';
...
const { component } = render(MyComponent, {});
...
```

Jest Config

```js
module.exports = {
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.svelte$': ['svelte-jester', { preprocess: true, debug: true }],
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'svelte'],
  roots: ['<rootDir>/app/modules'],
  modulePaths: ['<rootDir>/app/modules'],
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'app/modules'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    '<rootDir>/app/modules/tests/setupTest.js',
    '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect',
  ],
  clearMocks: true, // Automatically clear mock calls and instances before every test.
};
```

I am setting the default style to `SCSS` in the svelte config

svelte.config.js

```js
const preprocess = require('svelte-preprocess');

module.exports = {
  preprocess: preprocess({ defaults: { style: 'scss' } }),
};
```

Error Stack

```
Colon is expected
4:     padding: 20px;
5: 
6:     span {
              ^
7:       font-weight: bold;
8:     }
ParseError: Colon is expected

      at error (node_modules/svelte/src/compiler/utils/error.ts:25:16)
      at Parser$1.error (node_modules/svelte/src/compiler/parse/index.ts:101:3)
      at Object.read_style [as read] (node_modules/svelte/src/compiler/parse/read/style.ts:31:11)
      at tag (node_modules/svelte/src/compiler/parse/state/tag.ts:189:27)
      at new Parser$1 (node_modules/svelte/src/compiler/parse/index.ts:53:12)
      at parse (node_modules/svelte/src/compiler/parse/index.ts:218:17)
      at Object.compile (node_modules/svelte/src/compiler/compile/index.ts:93:14)
      at compiler (node_modules/svelte-jester/dist/transformer.cjs:135:32)
      at Object.processSync [as process] (node_modules/svelte-jester/dist/transformer.cjs:111:12)
      at ScriptTransformer.transformSource (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:464:35)
```

To reproduce clone and run this repo
https://github.com/rparsh/svelte-testing-scss

Comment: Is the `svelte.config.js` file in the root of your project?

Comment: yes its located at root where jest config is located @Phil

Comment: Looking at the [svelte-preprocess docs](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess/blob/main/docs/preprocessing.md), I don't actually see a `defaults` option. Are you sure your config file is correct?

Comment: @Phil yes its supported i am able to compile the build. It seems they remove it from docs few months back https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess/commit/a583e94f98a801096e96915e70e21617b29c5fea

Answer (score 4):

Add `lang="scss"` to the `<style>` tag:

```html
<style lang="scss">
</style>
```

In general it's no longer recommended to use default languages because of issues like this. You can't be sure that all tooling in the ecosystem supports reading the defaults. That's also why this setting was removed from the docs and `svelte-preprocess` now prints a warning that you should no longer use it.